# Installation failed due to: ''package install-create -r -t --user current --full --dont-kill --skip-verification -S 4608136'

Tags: android, android-studio, installation, build

What is the solution to this problem?
Installation failed due to: ''package install-create -r -t --user current --full --dont-kill --skip-verification -S 4608136' returns error 'Unknown failure: cmd: Failure calling service package: Broken pipe (32)''

The code of Manifest file is this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mainproject">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".SearchActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".WishlistMovie" />
        <activity android:name=".WishListTv" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Main13Activity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|screenLayout" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Main12Activity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|screenLayout" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Main11Activity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|screenLayout" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Main10Activity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|screenLayout" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Main8Activity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|screenLayout" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Main7Activity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|screenLayout" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Main6Activity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|screenLayout" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Main5Activity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|screenLayout" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Main4Activity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|screenLayout" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Main3Activity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|screenLayout" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Main2Activity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|screenLayout" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|screenLayout">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And the code for build file is this

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.21'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And build file app module

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mainproject"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.7.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.7.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.3"
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0"
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha04'

    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer:core:10.0.5'
    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0"

    def room_version = "2.2.3" // check latest version from docs

    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.3'
    kapt 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.3'

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Damn, i got the Answer. I mean it worked. Basically, I had to cold boot my AVD as that was the one giving the problems. Learned a lot from this error. But yes, I'd love it if someone could explain why I got that error.